# Fast way to get li datas with selenium?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Thank you for checking this post.

I tried to get comments about a news.
One of the news has about 11k comments and among them, about 6k of comments were able to collect.
Here is the link : https://n.news.naver.com/mnews/article/comment/023/0003390153?sid=102
(Although it's a Korean page, it won't be a matter for you.)

You may notice that this is a mobile version of web page, and you will need to use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='u_cbox_page_more']").click()
```

till it shows the full comments.

The problem is, the way I chose to get data was way slow. It took more than an hour and I had to interrupt it.
This is the code I used.

```
content = []
name = []
r_time = []

comment_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='u_cbox_list']/li")
              
for comment in comment_list:
    try:
        con = comment.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='u_cbox_contents']").text
        content.append(con)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        continue

    name.append(comment.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='u_cbox_nick']").text)        
    r_time.append(comment.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='u_cbox_date']").text)
```

I have much more news to crawl, and I can't take a risk to sit down and wait till it fetches all the comment. There should be a better way to collect it.
I tried to find a way with using Java Script but I couldn't find the one which was written for selenium with python. Sadly, I am not familiar with JavaScript itself.

But if there is a way and someone can show me some example with this, I can learn fast.
Hopefully, someone enlighten me please.
Thank you for your time, and thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reduced of getting comments from this page up to about 17 minutes (11 minutes - clicking on show more link, 6 minutes - getting data).

Code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://n.news.naver.com/mnews/article/comment/023/0003390153?sid=102')

content = []
name = []
r_time = []

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "u_cbox_page_more")))    # need for click by JS

while True:
    try:
        driver.execute_script("document.querySelector(\".u_cbox_paginate[style=''] .u_cbox_page_more\").click(); window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
        # WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "u_cbox_page_more"))).click()
        # WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".u_cbox_page_more"))).click()
        # WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='u_cbox_page_more']"))).click()
    except:
        break

comment_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='u_cbox_list']/li")

for comment in comment_list:
    try:
        con = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].querySelector('.u_cbox_contents').innerText;", comment)
        content.append(con)
    except Exception:
        continue

    name.append(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].querySelector('.u_cbox_nick').innerText;", comment))
    r_time.append(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].querySelector('.u_cbox_date').innerText;", comment))
```

**Bonus**. In the code above you can see 4 ways how to show all comments. I compared them:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|    locator type     |       time, s    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          JS         |        656.9     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       class name    |        728.1     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         css         |        736.5     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        xpath        |        774.3     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Even more thank you fir your thoughtful Bonus with the view_more codes! That is way better than the one I used. It will definitely help my works in future as well. - I tried my code above before I get sleep and it hasn't done scraping for about 6 hours.(well, not only with this page, but when I woke up, it was dealing with this page) Thank you again. Hope I can treat you with a beer or something if you get to Korea someday.